# Substrate Node and Docker Compose

Tags: substrate-node-template, docker

The [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/autoupdate_polkadot-v0.9.30_2022-09-28_12-57-56/docker-compose.yml) file has been removed from the [Substrate Node Template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template).

I previously found that using Docker Compose is a great way to get started with the node.
The `docker-compose.yml` file is independent from the codebase and relies on the Docker image `paritytech/ci-linux:production`, so it is still working the same way for me.

This all made me wonder about the following:

- Why was it removed from the project? Are there some downsides I should be aware of?
- Is there a recommended way to run a node with Docker? I have noticed the [Substrate Builder Docker Image](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/docker), but I am not too sure about it. Would I need it if I editing the node code, writing custom runtimes, adding palets, etc?

**Note:** As of the time of writing this, the latest commit in the Substrate Node Template is https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/commit/6a8b2b12371395979099d2c79ccc1860531b0449

Comment: Here is the PR removeing it: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/13437

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps: A [repository](https://github.com/anagolay/repa) targeting a production setup of a relay and parachain was [recently announced](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/repa-relaychain-and-parachain-production-setup/2264).

I'm not privy to why that compose file was removed. I do know that substrate is being moved under polkadot, so this change may be related to those changes?